# Regex to test string contain a specific pattern and exclude specific symbol using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to test a specific pattern using JavaScript.

Following is scenario.

I don't want to allow comma (**,**) in a string. For example 12,34 should return false and rest anything gives true.

I have read some tutorial to exclude some character using ^. As simple example I am doing something like this

```
/[^,][1-9]/g.test('12,34')
```

but it give true. Although I exclude the comma.

Valid result should be 12.34 or 1234 etc. but not 12,34.

I want to extend this to later (12.34) or (ABC) etc. as valid where string start with '**(**' and ends with '**)**' and can contain anything inside except comma.

Comment: Why do you want to allow ABC? Can you give some context of what you try to parse?

Comment: Plug your regxp into a regexp tester such as regex101 and take a look a the English-like description of what it is doing.

Comment: Is it more complicated than `/^[\d.]+$/`?

Comment: @torazaburo that regex could match strings like `.......`, that's why the "ugly" 2nd regex of my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your regex and use anchors like this:

```
^[^,]+$
```

This pattern will match string where the line starts and ends with whatever string not having a comma

On the other hand, if you want to allow 12.34, 1234 or ABC patterns, then you could use:

```
^[\dA-Z]+(?:\.[\dA-Z]+)?$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/LSkvh1/1)**

Comment: Your first regexp will match only a string of a single character which is not a comma.

Comment: @torazaburo, oops... typo. Good eye. Thanks, fixed

Comment: @SebastianProske true, thanks for the improvement, fixed.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza, can you please explain in the second pattern what does ?: mean in this (?:\.[\dA-Z]+)? and thanks for super answer.

Comment: @Entwickler the `(?:`...`)` it is just a non capturing group, it will improve the performance. If you use for instance a pattern `a(b)` this will match the strings `ab` and will capture the `b`, but if you use `a(?:b)` it will match `ab` and won't capture anything